# Angular HttpClientModule undefined

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I can't get the HttpClientModule, the following error appears while loading this ModuleType. I get this error in the registerNgModuleType method from Angular.

```
function registerNgModuleType(ngModuleType) {
    if (ngModuleType.ɵmod.id !== null) {
        /** @type {?} */
        const id = ngModuleType.ɵmod.id;
        /** @type {?} */
        const existing = (/** @type {?} */ (modules.get(id)));
        assertSameOrNotExisting(id, existing, ngModuleType);
        modules.set(id, ngModuleType);
    }
```

> "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

This my app.module.ts file
app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StartComponent } from './start/start.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { SelectLanguageComponent } from './select-language/select-language.component';
import { PersonComponent } from './person/person.component';
import { DynamicFormQuestionComponent } from './question/question.component';
import { DynamicFormComponent } from './dynamic-form/dynamic-form.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StartComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    SelectLanguageComponent,
    PersonComponent,
    DynamicFormQuestionComponent,
    DynamicFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule,  
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thie error is not related with ```httpClientModule``` I gues.. Can you share your code and mention in which line exactly you get the error??

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot of error that you are getting in console ??

Comment: Why do you think this error has something to do with the HttpClientModule?
 It seems to me that ngModulType.emod is not defined and that's the issue.

Comment: yes, it is not defined when the HttpClientModule is loading..

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that there was a dependency missing for that package!

Comment: Hello, how did you solve it? What dependencies were you missing?

Comment: I just deleted the folder with the node_modules in the project file and then restarted my Visual Studio Code and just run 'npm install' and the problem was gone.

Comment: Thanks! I've solved it now. I took out the flashmessages and everything worked well from there. I