# Can't find HttpClientModule in Angular 14

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Here's my environment information:

```
Angular CLI: 14.0.2
Node: 16.15.1
Package Manager: npm 8.11.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.0.2
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.2
@angular-devkit/core            14.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.2
@schematics/angular             14.0.2
rxjs                            7.5.5
typescript                      4.7.4
```

I'm trying to add this line:

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

to the app.module.ts, but angular says it can't find it.  I tried deleting the node_modules directory as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60578027/angular-httpclientmodule-undefined) and then rerunning npm install, but it didn't help.  Visual Studio Code hasn't pulled the files back in as it was suggested.

I do see a few modules in @angular/common like this will import successfully:

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
```

I made the following change to app.module.ts, but I get the error (Cannot find HttpClientModule):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { QuoteData } from './quotes/quotedata';
import { QuotesComponent } from './quotes/quotes.component';
//import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common';  //Why can't angular find this?

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    QuotesComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [QuoteData],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You say you added this line: `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';` But the code you posted has `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common';` - no http.

Answer (score 0):

You added the import statement at top, but did you declare it in your ngModule imports? Also, in the future it would be useful to post the code under discussion - in this case app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // import HttpClientModule after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I think I tried that earlier, but I definitely tried it just now and it didn't work.

Comment: You must have both the file import AND the ngModule import. When you say "cannot find httpclientModule, what is the specific error?

Answer (score 0):

Please use 
**import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http/index';**

instead of 
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

Comment: Please, read the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http), your answer is erroneous

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm using Angular 16, and only "import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http' " worked for me.